# PHP static property with extending class overwritten

Tags: php, oop, static, extending, extending-classes

Please, could you help me a bit with my problem?

I have class called Translateable and then clasess Article and Banner, which extend this class.

Problem occurs, when I do this:

```
$article = (new Article)->find(15);
$banner =  (new Banner)->find(1);

$articleTrans = $article->trans(); // method trans is method from Translateable
```

When I call `$article->trans();` I expect output like this:

```
App\Models\ArticleTrans
Article
```

but it return this:

```
App\Models\ArticleTrans
Banner
```

First row is ok, but the second one if bad and I don't know, how to solve this problem. 
I need to have **$instance** stored as static property.

Could you give me you help?

```
  class Translateable extends Model {

        static $transLang = null;
        static $transClass = null;
        static $instance = null;

        public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {

            static::$transLang = App::getLocale();

            parent::$transClass = static::$transClass;
            parent::$instance = static::$instance;
            parent::__construct($attributes);

        }
        /**
         * get items trans
         *
         * @param null $lang
         * @return mixed
         */
         public function trans($lang = null) {
              if($lang == null) {
                 $lang = static::$transLang;
              }

                  echo static::$transClass;
                  echo class_basename(static::$instance);
                  die();

              }
              public static function find($primaryKeyVal, $columns = []) {

                 $tci = new static::$transClass;
                 $item = static::withTrans()->where(static::$instance->getTable() . '.' . static::$instance->primaryKey, '=', $primaryKeyVal)->where($tci->getTable() . '.lang', '=', static::$transLang)->first();
    return $item;

        }
    }

class Article extends Translateable {
        static $transClass = 'App\Models\ArticleTrans';

        public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {

            parent::$transClass = static::$transClass;
            parent::$instance = $this;

            parent::__construct($attributes);

        }
 }

class Banner extends Translateable {

    static $transClass = 'App\Models\BannerTrans';

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {

        parent::$transClass = static::$transClass;
        parent::$instance = $this;

        parent::__construct($attributes);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using `statics` without understanding what they are. It looks like you should be using class properties. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php for more info on static.

Comment: Oh, and could you provide me code example please?

Comment: Nope but the docs for class properties can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: I edit my code to version in my question, what is bad now?

Comment: All you did was remove `public`... they're still all static.

Comment: Yeah, I thought, it is the fail, you mean.
So what should I do? 
When I remove "static" I cannot access them in static method. 
I'm quite confused.

Comment: There are no static methods in the code you've shown us. Do you know why you're using `static`?

Comment: I need it to be static, because I access it in another method, not just in methods in code I post... 
I add method, where I access it too.. and this method need to be static... because it's method from Laravel framework and I overwrite it...

Comment: Ah. Don't know much about Laravel so can't really comment. All I can say is as your code is, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to. Perhaps somebody else has a better idea of how to get this to work with these constraints.

Comment: No problem, I know, I have failure in my code, but I don't know, where and how to solve it.
Anyway, don't you have any idea, how to prevent revriwing **$instance** property content?

Comment: @JanKožušník method from which part of the Laravel framework? I assume the `Model` base class is self written because I don't see a Laravel namespace. Therefor I'm convinced Laravel doesn't use any static properties by default to be used somewhere as an accessor for class assets. Could you post only the relevant parts where you say _because it's a method from the Laravel framework and I overwrite it_?

Comment: I didn't post namespace, my model is extending laravel5 default model. I'm not sure how really laravel5 make it, anyway, you're right, because e.g. `$primaryKey` or `$table` are non static properties. But then, how do they access it in methods, called like this: `Model::find()` ? It's static method in which you cannot access non-static properties.